# Why is the question title a link that just takes you back to the question you are viewing?

Tags: discussion

I ask this question mostly because I am curious if I am missing something but when a question is open, the title is a link that just reloads the open question.

Is there a reason for this feature that I am missing?

Comment: Right-click, "Copy Link Location" for example. Easier than selecting and copying from the address bar of the browser.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Or just click share and then copy. I have always found this a little odd too.

Comment: Why does the icon on the home page of a site always link to... the home page?  Because the icons on the other pages link there also.  Granted, that's not quite the same situation here, but it is nice that the title of the post is the link to the post as a convention; that's how most blogs work too.

Comment: Right click and open in new tab, then go back to whatever question referenced the one you opened briefly to see if it was interesting :)

Answer (score 6):

It has its uses. For me, its most compelling use is while editing a post. I sometimes like to remind myself what the original post looked like. I can't think of any other *consistent* way to get a link to the still-unedited post except by the title link.

If you click "edit" and you go to a dedicated edit page (which is what happens for me here on Meta right now), you *could* middle-click the browser's "back" button to open the original page in a new tab. If clicking "edit" puts you into in-place-edit mode, though, then middle-clicking the "back" button will take you somewhere else.

If you're in in-place-edit mode, you *could* copy the URL from the browser's address bar and paste it in a new tab, but if you're on a dedicated edit page, that URL won't be what you want.

I'm unaware of any place to get a link to the original page that works in *either* edit mode, except in the question title.

Even when not editing, the question title link is handy. When I'm browsing on a tablet and I want to copy the URL of the current page, that link is a bigger target to click than either the "share" link or the browser address bar. It's also a bigger click target than the "refresh" button, which is useful when there have been several changes to a page while I've been away.

Comment: I would also add it is nice for forcing a refresh for brand new pages which sometimes don't show the "Has been updated text" quickly enough.